# Getting Blurred Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, onblur

I have binded blur on an input. On blur, I want to use `$(this)` and detect this input. Is there a way to do that?

```
<input data-john="x" data-doe="false">

$('[data-john=x]:not([data-doe=true])').blur(function() {
    console.log($(this))
})
```

In this example, `$(this)` is returning Window, not the blurred element.

Is there a way to get input using `$(this)`?

Comment: It doesn't return window, except if you overwrote `$` function to do so. If it is still jQuery's `$`, then `$(anything)` returns a jQuery object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('input')` with `blur()` event and have `this` or `$(this)` in your `console.log`:

```js
$('input').blur(function() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log($(this).data('john'));
  console.log($(this).data('doe'));
  console.log($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-john="x" data-doe="false">
```

Comment: It was a typo. I updated the question. Can you please check?

Comment: You can still use the same code. I just did minor update of adding your HTML to my snippet. Please check.